# Class reference after orientation change

Tags: android, multithreading, orientation-changes

i wrote a public class, which handle a ethernet communication, has some thread that update some variables.

The main activity interact with this class getting the variables or to send some messages.
So after a orientation change thread are running as I want but the main activity it can not get datas from the "ethernet class".

How I declare the class in the main activity:

EthIp = new EthIp(tot_in, tot_out, IP , Port, false);

Start thread in the EthIP class

Thank you for hlep...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When orientation changed your activity should have recreated and a new ethernet class instance created. You have to avoid activity recreate.
change your manifest as...

```
    <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
```

and then override onConfigurationChanged() in the activity as ...

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Libin, this works as I wanted... A doubt, this solution doesn't prevents me to change layout or fragment in that activity? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, If you need to have different layout for portrait/landscape , then your activity have to recreated. but when it recreate activity  savedInstanceState will not be null. you have to save your state on orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that at default Activity is destroyed and then created a new one during orientation change ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android))

Make sure you close eth connection in OnClose/OnPause method of an Activity and that the threads you create behave appropriately when you restart your Activity.